# How to parse syntax using OWL API?

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I am a beginner in OWL API and am learning how to parse **functional** syntax. So far I have been unable to do it, and cannot figure out where I am going wrong.
For example, consider a short and simple OWL file having the following(just a random example) -

`EquivalentClasses(:TestPizza ObjectIntersectionOf(DataMinCardinality(20 :hasToppingValue xsd:double) :Pizza))`

The problem is I can't even create an OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser variable since it is showing undefined( I am using the latest version - 5.1.18).

Could anyone help by providing a code example on how to parse it?

Comment: what exactly is showing "undefined"? The class exists for sure, check your Maven dependencies then

Comment: I can import the class, thats not the problem. Actually I don't know how to instantiate the variable. Like I used InputStream for a string input axiom as per documentation but they haven't been updated since version 4, so its wrong now. So I am stuck in sort of how to "create" and "parse".

Comment: @UninformedUser

Answer (score 1):

There is a misunderstanding here on what parsing functional syntax looks like.
A functional syntax axiom is not self standing - it must be part of an ontology. This would include prefix declarations and an ontology declaration.

For Manchester syntax, there are classes to parse a string that represents just an axiom or a class expression; however, that requires manual management of namespaces. For functional syntax, these classes do not exist. To parse a string, it must contain an ontology declaration, as a minimum. Then parsing happens just like for any other language - e.g., with a StringDocumentSource to take the string as input, and passed to an OWLOntologyManager for parsing. There are examples on the OWLAPI wiki on how to do that.

```
StringDocumentSource input=new StringDocumentSource("functional syntax string");
OWLOntology ontology = ontologyManager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(input);
```

Axioms are then available:

```
// stream of axioms
ontology.axioms();
```

Comment: So for example if I had an ontology with proper declarations, and the statement above in functional syntax, could I not parse it in such a way that I could get the classes and relations between them separately?
Like in Manchester Syntax you can simply do something like
`ManchesterOWLSyntaxParser parser = OWLManager.createManchesterParser();`
`parser.setStringToParse("Arm subClassOf (hasPart some Finger)");`
`OWLAxiom axiom = parser.parseAxiom();`

Comment: @UserNo1734238169870 see answer update

Comment: Thank you, I understand what to do now. Meanwhile, could you tell me which version of HermiT Reasoner works with OWL API 5.1.18?

Comment: The latest HermiT should work with no problems - 1.4.3.519 (the PATCH portion of the release number is the OWLPI version HermiT was built with - so 5.1.9)